# Mathjax templates dont work on local computer

Tags: html, mathjax

I have started to use Mathjax to develop a desktop app. I have found a very nice collection of examples and templates at: https://www.tuhh.de/MathJax/test/examples.html

However, whenever I download the HTML code of these files (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) and copy it into a Notepad++ file (with `.html` suffix), they don't work on any local computer i have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the relative path :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../MathJax.js?config=MML_HTMLorMML-full"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=MML_HTMLorMML-full"></script>
```

(see here to choose a cdn : http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html)

or download the js files to embed them localy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried this without any success.

Comment: @Thomas: try to save the entire web page (using `ctrl`+`s`). This should get all the external libraries and it should work

Answer (score 0):

I tried the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> with several computers and browsers, but it also doesn't work even when i change the source. I am explicitly interested in the following code: https://www.tuhh.de/MathJax/test/sample-dynamic.html
Here, the webpage can dynamically give an output in the MathJax format.